# Is there much significance to $\sin(1)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I explored this number, $\sin(1)$, which appears numerically on Google, but apparently not with any in-depth description.

I find it possibly an important constant, although I cannot remember seeing it before or having any direct use for it.

It involves simply the trigonometry of a unit circle and its radius, the y component of the crucial one radian angle.

Comment: It is also the imaginary part of $e^i$.

Comment: Interestingly, it is also a transcendental number

Comment: Why exactly do you think the one radian angle is crucial? 1 radian corresponds to $1/2\pi$ division of a circle, this does not seem particularly interesting.

Comment: Did you know there's a name for this constant? It's called the Krestovozdvizhensky constant, but the paper is in Belarusian, and besides, he himself wrote the paper,which was on some constructibility of sines of different angles,and a compendium of the angles they satisfy.

Comment: Yes, rational multiples of pi are interesting, but 1 is not a rational multiple.

Comment: This should be obvious, but I just had to say it. Make a circle with radius $r$ and center at $(0,0)$. The length of the arc of the circle, measured from $(r, 0)$ to $r(\cos 1, \sin 1)$ is $r$.